# Multiple input events vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, input, event-listener

Struggling to get all my input fields to work as intended.
The first field is working as it should but i want the **phone** input to change the **phone_field** to change as well.

How do i go around making this work with multiple fields?

```html
<div class="formBox">
  <label for="full_name">Fullt navn</label>
  <input name="name" type="text" id="fullname" />
</div>
<div class="formBox">
  <label for="phone">Tlf:</label>
  <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" />
</div>
<div class="formBox">
  <label for="email">Epost:</label>
  <input name="email" type="text" id="email" />
</div>

<div>
  <h3 id="full_name_field">Ola Normann</h3>
</div>

<p id="phone_field">+47 123 12 123</p>
```

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const name = document.getElementById('full_name_field');

input.addEventListener('input', updateValue);

function updateValue(e) {
  name.textContent = e.target.value;
}
```

Comment: Where do you ever define the variable `input`?  Surely your browser's development console is producing an error for that.  Define that variable and [your code works](https://jsfiddle.net/2b94gzvt/).

Comment: `input.addEventListener('input', updateValue);`: What's the `input` variable?

Comment: The code did work without a variable for it. After giving it one it still works, but i have problems doing this to the rest of the fields and have them update just like the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a function that updates phone_field and fires when a key is pressed in phone:

HTML:

```
<input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" onkeydown="updatePhoneField"/>
```

JS:

```
function updatePhoneField() {
    phoneVal = document.getElementById("phone").value;
    document.getElementById("phone_field").innerHTML = phoneVal;
}
```

Comment: Dont seem to work for me unless im doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that works ( for now ) probably not ideal and not the best way to do it but!

```
const input1 = document.getElementById("fullname");
const output1 = document.getElementById("full_name_field");

document.getElementById('fullname').onkeyup = function () {
"use strict";
document.getElementById('full_name_field').textContent = this.value}
```